# Task Scheduler Not Running task with Network Path

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks, azure-service-fabric, taskscheduler

I am working in a test development environment and I am creating a task in task scheduler that is using a remote network location to access an executable file. Although in my scenario that network address is of my own machine.
Like this

> \\MyComputerName\FolderOnMyPC\application.exe

Now I have given proper sharing access to the folder and I can access the executable via Explorer but when I create a task in Task Scheduler I am unable to run it. Although the task runs fine with the local disk path like this

> D:\FolderOnMyPC\application.exe

I have tried looking into this over the Internet but I am unable to find any workaround or the reason it is happening as I have given every possible access to the folders even in

> System32/Tasks

There are also some arguments that are specified in the arguments section of the Task Scheduler

**Edited**

I am sharing the code for executing the task.

```
public Task<int> Launch(string Path, string iniFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                TaskService taskService = new TaskService();

                const string TaskName = "LaunchTask";
                if (taskService.FindTask(TaskName) != null)
                {
                    var task = taskService.FindTask(TaskName);
                }

                iniFilePath = "\"" + iniFilePath + "\"";
                string completeArgument = "/portable /skipupdate " + iniFilePath;
                TaskDefinition taskDefinition = taskService.NewTask();            
                taskDefinition.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.S4U;
                taskDefinition.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(mt4Path, completeArgument, null));                          
                taskDefinition.Settings.Hidden = false;
                Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.Task mtTask = taskService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(TaskName, taskDefinition);
                RunningTask runningMT4 = mtTask.Run();
                int processIdMT = (int)runningMT.EnginePID;
                mt4Task.Folder.DeleteTask(mtTask.Name);
                return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(processIdMT);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Some extra information about the project is that I am working on a Service Fabric Project and its using it as its Service.

Comment: Task scheduler cannot "see" network drives when run as system, but may under a specified user account.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to say because its a system process as per my knowledge and should be able to see network. Right?

Comment: System service account can not see network shares.
Try setting it to run with a specified  user account that has the rights.
The system account is only local admin.

Comment: _"System service account can not see network shares."_. - Not true. It should be able to access the share via *UNC* path, if [the share grants permissions to the *machine account*](https://serverfault.com/a/135874), instead of a user.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You don't even appear to be configuring Task Scheduler via any code (never mind C#), but even if you were, the issue is not related to the programming, but rather just to how Task Scheduler behaves. Task Scheduler is _not_ "a tool primarily used for programming", and so questions about using it are not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have added more explanation to the question and I hope it helps someone else. Thank You for pointing my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to look into the other direction probably although I may have found a solution that can very much be a workaround but hope it helps someone else like me. The problem was in this line

```
taskDefinition.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.S4U;
```

Now seeing the documentation on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382075(v=vs.85).aspx) I found out about my issue

> **TASK_LOGON_S4U**
>
> Use an existing interactive token to run a task. The user must log on
>   using a service for user (S4U) logon. When an S4U logon is used, no
>   password is stored by the system and there is no access to either the
>   network or encrypted files.

So I changed my task logon type to the Service Account and supplied the NETWORKSERVICE as user id and it resolved my issue.
here is the updated code attached

```
   public Task<int> Launch(string Path, string iniFilePath)
            {
                try
                {
                    TaskService taskService = new TaskService();

                    const string TaskName = "LaunchTask";
                    if (taskService.FindTask(TaskName) != null)
                    {
                        var task = taskService.FindTask(TaskName);
                    }

                iniFilePath = "\"" + iniFilePath + "\"";
                string completeArgument = "/portable /skipupdate " + iniFilePath;
                TaskDefinition taskDefinition = taskService.NewTask();            
                taskDefinition.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.ServiceAccount;
                taskDefinition.Principal.UserId = @"NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE";
                taskDefinition.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(mt4Path, completeArgument, null));                          
                taskDefinition.Settings.Hidden = false;
                Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.Task mtTask = taskService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(TaskName, taskDefinition);
                RunningTask runningMT4 = mtTask.Run();
                int processIdMT = (int)runningMT.EnginePID;
                mt4Task.Folder.DeleteTask(mtTask.Name);
                return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(processIdMT);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

The reason to do this was because I am running this under a Service Fabric project and service fabric was using network service to launch it's tasks.

Comment: FYI, in case you need to secure access to a file or securable object, generally you wouldn't want to grant access to every "NETWORK SERVICE" process. When running a task as "NETWORK SERVICE" or "LOCAL SERVICE", the process Token should have an "NT TASK" SID based on the task name. If the task is in a folder, replace backslashes in the path with hyphens. For example, a task named "Spam\LaunchTask" would have the SID "NT TASK\Spam-LaunchTask" in its Token. Once the service task is created, its SID is registered with the system, and you can use it to grant access, e.g. for files via icacls.exe.

Comment: @eryksun yes I did the same thing in production.